# Position of year date in moderntimeline

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, moderncv, moderntimeline

In this example, the

> 2012

seems to be further away from the blue bar than the

> 2010

is. Can the

> 2012

be moved toward the bar, so that the

> 2012

and the

> 2010

are equidistant to the blue bar?

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[firstyear=2004,lastyear=2014]{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{etoolbox}           
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};  }  }
        {#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}  }
\makeatother%

\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\tlcventry{2010}{2012}{test}{}{test}{}{test}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you mean vertically, you can replace `\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}` with `\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-3pt}`. Note that the rest of the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is not needed for `\tlcventry`.

Comment: @karlkoeller this only moves down the 2010 and the 2012 stays where it is. I want to move the 2012 downwards.. and the other command \pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textENDabove{\tl@width-2pt} wont change anything.

Comment: i only want to move the 2012 a little downwards while the rest stays the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to move "2012" a little downwards you can redefine `\tltextend` to be (added `1pt` to `below`):

```
\renewcommand{\tltextend}[2][north east]{%
   \tikzset{
       tl@endyear/.style={
           font=#2,
           name=tl@endyear,
           below=1pt, % it was originally null
           inner xsep=0pt,
           anchor=#1,
       }
   }
}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[firstyear=2004,lastyear=2014]{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\renewcommand{\tltextend}[2][north east]{%
   \tikzset{
       tl@endyear/.style={
           font=#2,
           name=tl@endyear,
           below=1pt, % it was null
           inner xsep=0pt,
           anchor=#1,
       }
   }
}
\makeatother%

\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\tlcventry{2010}{2012}{test}{}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image]